# Что означает слово "хам"?

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, этимология

Откуда оно произошло и когда его уместно применять?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Слово *хамство*, как и *хам*, имеет два значения.

**1.** Разговорно-устаревшее — **невежество**.
Презрительное название крепостного крестьянина, а также человека, принадлежащего к низшим сословиям общества (уст.).

*— В третьем классе дозволяется ехать одним только мужикам, то есть хамам* (А. Чехов. Гусев).

*— Он там дворовых людей по-французски учить вздумал! Это, дескать, ему полезно! Хаму-то, слуге-то!* (Ф. Достоевский).

*— Это только мужики женятся рано, но там, известно, хамство, а вы-то с чего?* (А. Чехов. Учитель словесности).

Значение слова ***Хам*** по словарю Даля:

м. хаму(ы)га, хамовщина, хамово колено, отродье, бранное прозвище лакеев, холопов или слуг; крепостной. Хамство ср. хамовщина ж. лакейщина. Из хама не будет пана. По бороде Авраам, а по делам — Хам. Ходит Хам по лавке, в хамовой рубашке: открою я окошко, выдь Хам вон! (дым в черной избе). При нем все хамы служат, подлый народ, люди низкого рода и безусловные поклонники. Хамоватый человек, холоповатый, неуч.

Есть ещё хамовник — стар. ткач, полотнянщик, скатертник, откуда и название части города в Москве, Хамовники. Хамовное дело, ткацкое, полотняное и браное. Хамовить — арх. скитаться без приюта, по миру. Хамойка ж. смол. судомойка, вихоть, пучок мочала. Хаметь — влад. говоры — понимать, разуметь. | Становиться хамом.

В современности значение **невежество** присоединилось ко второму значению.

**2. Грубость, наглость** (хамское поведение; допустить хамство). Употребляют  как бранное слово.

*— Хам! - крикнула она и плюнула через решетчатую калитку в лицо парню. - Как ты смеешь оскорблять офицера...* (К. Паустовский. Далекие годы).

История слова связана с Библией. Хам (ивр. «горячий») — библейский персонаж, переживший Всемирный потоп, один из трёх сыновей Ноя, брат Иафета и Сима (Быт. 5:32; 6:10), легендарный прародитель африканских народов, давший начало понятию «хамства», которое означает пренебрежительное отношение к культурным запретам.

Согласно Библии, Хам повёл себя постыдным образом во время опьянения своего отца Ноя. Он увидел и рассказал братьям про наготу отца своего (Быт. 9:22). Обычно это место трактуется как насмешка и неуважение к отцу, что в дальнейшем вошло в содержание термина хамство. Почитание родителей было обязательным, а нагота считалась постыдной.

Об употреблении хорошо вот здесь:
[Хам — это кто такой? Каково происхождение и значение слова "хам"?](http://fb.ru/article/140709/ham---eto-kto-takoy-kakovo-proishojdenie-i-znachenie-slova-ham)

Answer (score 2):

Это слово означает *грубиян* и происходит (по Фасмеру) от имени собственного – Хам, сын Ноя (библ.) Раньше означало *слуга, крепостной, мужик*.